# Is there any low bandwidth VoIP software for Android?

Tags: skype, voip, bandwidth

I have measured Skype's bandwidth consumption:

- When just running Skype: ~0.09 KB/s
- When talking to someone through Skype: ~9 KB/s

Is there any VoIP software available in the Android Market that consumes less bandwidth?

**NOTE**: I'd like to be able to talk to someone on Ubuntu with this client, so it should also have a Linux version or be compatible with another Linux client/network.

P.S.: Are my measurements correct?

Comment: Thats pretty low bandwidth... What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why does it need to be so low?

Comment: lower bandwidth usage :)

Comment: `P.S.: Are my measurements correct?` How do you do your measurement?

Comment: Android shows the traffic. I used skype for talking, and just on "stand-by" and i did the math

Comment: i already tried the following VOIP apps: tango, google voice, Skype, viber - there are all not good:\

Answer (score 4):

Get the [pcgod's mumble client for android](https://github.com/pcgod/mumble-android/downloads) (don't get it from the market because the market one is not the pcgod uploader and is very old and not updated).

Mumble is an open source VOIP client that is available for windows and linux. However, this VOIP is a client-server one , hence requires both the clients to connect to a server. While you may choose a public server in the list when launching the desktop application of mumble, it's better to configure and setup your own mumble server so that you have more choice of freedom and you can even set the voice quality and codec that can use lesser bandwidth. Further, mumble is more like Push to Talk, so it uses very little bandwidth (I was torrenting on my 256k connection while using mumble with just 2 people in the room and still it was fine!)

Comment: @LanceBaynes Did you check this app? For precise bandwidth requirements , read http://mumble.sourceforge.net/FAQ/English#What_are_the_bandwidth_requirements.3F

Answer (score 4):

Bandwidth consumption depends on the codec that the app will use. Skype uses SILK or G729 (see wikipedia for their bandwidth consumption).

You can see here http://searchvoip.techtarget.com.au/articles/23239-VoIP-codecs-Day-Three-Low-bandwidth-codecs more low bandwidth codecs and search for an application that support one of them.

I have used SipDroid that has support for SILK and Speex too.
For linux client you can use SFLphone or ekiga. I have used both with Asterisk and SipDroid and worked quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try with [Fring](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy0WWgipkUw&feature=player_embedded), i don't know about the bandwidth but it does allow Google Talk.

You can also check [What is Fring](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNKV40vlnls&feature=relmfu)

If fring does not convinced you try [TruPhone](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.truphone.andrd)

Although if you ask me i'm quite sure that you won't be able to win skype app bandwidth usage on their own application, i mean they must (or should) know their stuff.

Let Me know